# wordpress-Add Remember me username on custom login form

Tags: wordpress

I need to add remember me checkbox for username on custom login form.Like when user will fill the username and password and if he check remember me option then i nedd to save his username.I have created a cutom login form and after submit this is my code.but it does not remember username.

```
$username = sanitize_user($_POST['email']);
$password = $_POST['password'];

$remember = $_POST["rememberme"];

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = $remember; 
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
//$user1 = apply_filters('authenticate', null, $username, $password);

if ( is_wp_error($user) ) 
{
    echo $user->get_error_message();

}elseif ( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'has_to_be_activated', true ) != false ) 
{

    $user = new WP_Error('activation_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: User is not activated.'));
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}else{

    $secure_cookie = is_ssl() ? true : false;
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, $secure_cookie );
    echo "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.problogdesign.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-wordpress-login-form-overlay/) documentation.

It will help you.